# batch extract part of a variable (substring)

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables

I have programs with some of them having 64bit versions:
foo.exe
bar.exe
bar64.exe etc.
So wanted to extract 2 last characters from a filename (without extension) and do something then...

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%G in ('dir /b *.exe') do (
set _test=%%G
set _result=!_test:~-2!

echo !_result!
)

endlocal
exit
```

This works well if the number of characters to extract IS NOT 2. If it is 2 then echo goes crazy.
Is it me doing things wrong or some bug?

Comment: Please define "goes crazy." What does it do that you don't want it to do, or not do that you want it to do, and with what data?

Comment: At some point it starts to print out part of the code: > (
set _test=bar64
 set _result=!_test:~-2!
 echo !_result!
)
64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did use the whole file name, since `.exe` is four chars the error you describe shouldn't occur.
To avoid unexpected behavior simple prepend the name with any two chars.

```
@echo off&setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b *.exe') do (
    set "_test=__%%~nG"
    set _result=!_test:~-2!
    echo:!_result!
)
```

**Edit** To avoid echo status being reported, use a different command separator than a space.

Comment: This actually didn't work, but gave a helpful hint - removed "delims=." to get the filename with extension and then extraction of last 6 chars succeeded. So it does have something to do with dots and extensions. Thanks.

Comment: Found the problem :) One filename ended with "on" which triggered ECHO ON. LOL.